# Logical assignment operator in PHP

Tags: php, logical-operators, assignment-operator, short-circuiting

There doesn't seem to be a logical assignment operator in PHP. I would like to be able to write `$a = $a || $b` as `$a ||= $b`.

Note that this is not the same as `$a |= $b`, which does not short-circuit when `$a` evaluates to `true`.

Is there such functionality in PHP?

Comment: And what should `$a ||= $b` do? `$a = $a || $b` ?!

Comment: That's what I want, yes!

Comment: That doesn't make much sense with a logical operator.

Comment: Why not? Can you elaborate, please?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `$a = ($a == 'test' ? $c:$b);` so if $a === 'test' then $a will get the value of $c else $a gets the value of $b?

Comment: No, I just want to write `$a = $a || $b` without having to type `$a` twice, the same way I can write `$a = $a | $b` as `$a |= $b`.

Comment: @JacquesKoekemoer `$a = ($a == 'test' ? $c:$b);` ... `$a === 'test'` ??? Then `$a | $b` ??? that is a bitwise operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't appear to have this functionality. There is nothing in the [Assignment Operator documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) or in the [Logical Operators documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) that mentions this functionality. Also, it isn't included in the [top rated comment on the Assignment Operator page](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#40084), which is a list that someone compiled of all of the assignment operators from information in the other pages.

Comment: This does not answer the question. I am asking about a logical assignment operator, with short-circuiting: `$A = true; $A ||= ThisFunctionIsShortCircuitedAndWillNotBeExecuted()` and `$B = false; $B &&= ThisFunctionIsShortCircuitedAndWillNotBeExecuted()`.

Comment: I missed the part about short circuiting and edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: Wikipedia lists Zend Technologies as the developer of PHP so I sent them an e-mail asking if logical assignment operators exist or if they plan on implementing them. If I get a response that answers the question, I'll include it in my answer because I want some sort of definitive response and I'd like to have it posted somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for you input, @DaveF. I was not the one who down voted your answer, so I cannot remove it. I was actually a bit surprised when my 2,5 year old question got an answer, and it was already down voted when I saw it.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. The down vote came after you responded and before any other answers were posted.

Answer (score 1):

There is no `||=` or `&&=` operator in PHP, there are some languages that use this (such as [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)) but they've implemented it differently.

So the only way to do it is like so:

```
$a = $b || $c;
```

You can also use the `??` operator, it means if `isset` then use.

```
$a = $b ?? $c;
```

Or chain values to it and use the last as default (if none of the previous evaluate to true):

```
$a = $b ?? $c ?? true;
```

Logical assignment operators only allow you to store a `true` or a `false` value and, most of the time, you can directly put (and optionally set) it in the if statement directly to save a line of code.